# Family-friendly hamam in Istanbul with men's and women's sections open at the same time

Tags: turkey, family, istanbul

There are countless hamams (Turkish baths) in Istanbul, but I'm looking for what is apparently an unusual combination of features:

- Has men's and women's sections open *at the same time* (many smaller places alternate hours)
- Allows children 10+ years old (many are officially or in practice adults only)
- Do not require signing up for some €100+ spa package (like most of the touristy ones near Sultanahmet)
- Bonus: Historical and at least basic English is spoken

I've found many that tick 3 out of 4, eg. [Kılıc Ali Pasa Hamam](https://kilicalipasahamami.com/) would be *perfect* if only they didn't swap the whole place between men and women at 4pm.  [Suleymaniye](https://www.suleymaniyehamami.com.tr/) comes up in many lists as family-friendly, but they're now 16+ only.  [Kadırga](https://kadirgahamami.com/) looks like it might work, but the reviews are quite polarizing, while [Sifa Hamami](https://www.sifahamami.com/) apparently has men & women in the same room, which is quite unusual -- and it's unclear if either accepts children.  Suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found a hamam that (just barely) ticks all the boxes: **[Cağaloğlu Hamamı](https://cagalogluhamami.com.tr/)**, which ironically enough is also one of the oldest and most famous hamams in Istanbul.  It's quite touristy and even [the most basic package](https://cagalogluhamami.com.tr/en/s/the-istanbul-dream/) costs a steep €60, but that's less than my self-imposed limit of €100, it has concurrently operating men's & women's sections, and children over the age of 6 are allowed.